# Issue with Exporting Records or Tables in Power BI/Excel

Tags: powerbi, odata, powerbi-desktop, record

I'm experiencing an issue in Power BI while attempting to expand records or tables from my custom API. The error message indicates that the retrieved data has a nested structure with multiple tables and relationships.

Specifically, the error implies that tables cannot be found. Additionally, when I attempt to copy the URL from the error, it appears that the resource does not exist.

I've tested expanding records with a minimal dataset, and the issue still persists.

I've also verified that the data types of the expanded fields match the expected types in power BI